# python installed in another directory

Tags: command-line, 16.04, python, directory, python3

I am using ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu 16.04 comes with python2 and python3.5 and I wanted python3.7 so I followed some instructions from a site and installed python3.7 manually by compiling its files and installing its dependencies.

It's working fine. The problem is that it is installed in `usr/local/bin` while I wanted it to be in `usr/bin`. besides I wanted python3 to point to python3.7 so I ran the following command

`sudo update-alternatives --config python3`

and it said that there is no alternative for python3.
Besides, when I downloaded python3.7, I unknowingly unzipped it in the home directory. Now the whole python directory is in my home directory, so does that mean, whenever I make any changes like installing a library (eg. matplotlib) it will be installed directly in `home/python3.7/lib`?

Comment: It still depends on how you install it.
If mathplotlib can use the libraries depends on your libpath and possible other environment variables required by mathplotlib.

If you don't require special compilation/installation options, and the package is not available in any repository. I would first try to install it from a launchpad publish ppa like this one for python 3.7, rather than compiling it. 
https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.7

Comment: since I have already compiled it, I should go with it anyway. how can I make python3 point to python3.7 that is present in usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 0):

While python is not rly integrated with dpkgs alternatives solution, you can change the link for python in /usr/bin

```
~$ ls -lt /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 márc   4  2019 /usr/bin/python -> python2
~$ ls -lt /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 szept 24 08:49 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5
~$ sudo ln -fs /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3
```

This is the fast and easy way.

If you add the source repository of 18.04, you may do `apt-get source python` and build your own python package. This will replace the installed python3.5, cause the package name is python3.

Another alternative to just install 3.7 from here:

https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Something like that:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

This will also wipes your python 3.5 for the same reason.

Comment: hey thanks ! I ran the commands to change the link for python in /usr/bin, But I didn't quit understand what happened there. Did I delete any files by that command or something ? also what happened to python3.5, because earlier python3 would run python3.5.